# Missing DirectX SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, directx

I have Window Server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio 2012 installed along with .NET framework 4.5.  I want to reference the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback in my VS2012 project.

However, I can't find any directX folder "DirectX for Managed Code"  at all under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET. I also do not see this dll under C:/Windows/assembly/GAC either

I can install Direct X sdk and it will but I don't recall having to do this on my other PCs (admittedly it uses Window 7)

I'm not very familiar with this part, am I missing certain component to install when I installed either Window 2008 or VS2012?

Comment: Which version of DX do you want to address? The newer ones (e.g. 11) come with the Windows SDK which gets installed when you install Visual Studio 2012. The older ones (e.g. 9) need the DirectX SDK. Btw, you should find the reference under "Framework". You should not choose a dll file.

Comment: On my other pc, it shows Runtime version v1.1.4322 and Version 1.0.2902.0.  As far as reference it through the Framework, that was the first step I tried and I was puzzled when I could not find the AudioVidoPlayback on it.  I think I'll try to reinstall VS2012 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this you will have to install the DirectX SDK as taken from MSDN (DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback):

> However, the minimum operating system that will run the samples and tools **in the DirectX 9.0 SDK** is Windows 2000.

See: [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further reference.

Also make sure to de-install VS2012 + runtimes before you install the DirectX SDK as it often gives trouble when installing VS first.